# Не работают ссылки на Google Play из Webview

Tags: java, android-studio, google-play

Здравствуйте.

Я создал вебвью в андроид студио через фулскрин-активити
Обернул вот этот сайт: http://gp-cpi.ru/index_games_en.html

Если открыть его в мобильном хроме, то ссылки ведут на Google Play на приложения, все работает корректно.
А из моей вьюхи ссылки не работают, скрин прилагаю [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне это исправить?

Сделал также empty activity, чтобы ничего не мешало. также не работает.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вашу проблему, то `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` - это то, что вам нужно. 
Документация к методу `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` в `WebViewClient` сообщает:

> If WebViewClient is not provided, by default WebView will ask Activity Manager to choose the proper handler for the url.

Убедитесь, что в вашем коде описан метод `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, который принимает решение, загружать урл в приложении PlayMarket или открывать его  `WebView`. Возможно, вам потребуется [парсить URL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) и [извлекать scheme](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getScheme%28%29).

*Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13886357/5110414*